# Drupal Google Translate Module - Must be represented in the url

Tags: 7

I have a Wordpress site which I'm planning on porting to Drupal to leverage more advanced functionality.

One plugin I use on the Wordpress site is for Google Translate. Most Wordpress plugins don't represent the language in the url (i.e. they use AJAX or Google Translate direct). I use a decent one which specifies the country code in the URL, and that allows me to use http://petfoodratings.org/ko/, or http://www.petfoodratings.org/de/.

Before undertaking a port to Drupal I want to know if any of the Google Translate Drupal modules do this in the same way?

Comment: But i think Google translate restricted features regarding this

Answer (score 1):

The only module I know of with a Drupal 7 version is [GTranslate](http://drupal.org/project/gtranslate).

> GTranslate uses Google power to translate your web page. With 58 available languages your site will be available to more than 98% of internet users.
>
> - Hides "Suggest better translation" pop-up
> - Hides Google top frame after translation
> - Mouse over effect
> - Analytics feature
> - Flags combined in one file to load faster
> - Option to open translated page in new window
> - Available styles Dropdown/Flags/flags with dropdown
> - Valid XHTML
> - Google Translate Element on your site (Google Default translation method)
> - Ability to use SEF URLs and edit translations with Pro version

The module is used from 2250 sites, and 1216 of those are using Drupal 7.

As for [the comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54407/drupal-google-translate-module-must-be-represented-in-the-url#comment57296_54407) written by [monymirza](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/10216/monymirza), The [Google TOS](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/archive/20070416/) once contained the following paragraph:

> 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. **You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers)** and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.

The [actual version](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) of the Google TOS says:

> Don't misuse our Services. For example, don't interfere with our Services or **try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide**. You may use our Services only as permitted by law, including applicable export and re-export control laws and regulations. We may suspend or stop providing our Services to you if you do not comply with our terms or policies or if we are investigating suspected misconduct.

I am not sure what they mean by *interface*. It could mean you can only access the service through the user interface provided by the browser.